# python: if I use a string the function works, with a variable doesn't

Tags: python, operating-system, rename

I'm writing an easy script for nautilus on Ubuntu and I get a strange error:
in a function a pass a variable with the selected file and it doesn't work but if I write the path as string (copied by a text file where the script wrote the variable) it does!

```
def estraiFile(elemento):
    folder = os.path.dirname(elemento)
    fl.write(elemento)
    metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(elemento) #NOT WORKING     
    metadata.read() 
    tag = metadata['Exif.Image.DateTime']   
    new_data = tag.value.strftime('/%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.jpg')     
    new_tempo = cartella + str(new_data) + estensione
    new_name = cartella + str(new_data)
    os.rename(elemento, new_name) #if I change elemento with a string copied from fl,WORKS!
    return
```

Comment: Print out the actual value of `elemento` and see what it is.

Comment: What is the value in each of `elemento`, `new_data`, `new_tempo`, `new_name`? That's the most elementary debugging technique; print values so you know what your code is dealing with. What exactly are you passing to the function: demonstrate with a call to the function.

Comment: elemento comes from `os.getenv("NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS")` and I don't know how to print it on the console (I get none) and so, as wrote, I print it on a text file (`fl.write(elemento)`) and it is a paht and if I copy it in place of elemento, the function works

Answer (score 1):

> in a function a pass a variable with the selected file 
>   and it doesn't work but if I write the path as string
>   (copied by a text file where the script wrote the variable) it does!

The most likely source of the error is that copy-and-paste is preserving a character coding difference that you can't see or reproduce by hand (perhaps a normalized vs unnormalized unicode).

To see the difference, add this add the first line of *estraiFile()*:

```
print(repr(elemento))
```

Unicode can make it hard to see the underlying cause without a diagnostic such as this.

**Addendum:**

From your comment, we can the the "invisible" difference.  The string, `'/media/photos/pippo/q.jpg\n'` has a `'\n'` at the end (this represents a newline character).  You can chop it off with *str.rstrip()*:

```
elemento = elemento.rstrip()
```

Comment: It is the backslash-n that is the problem.  Add this to your file:  ``elemento = elemento.rstrip()``.